# How to duplicate and rename a tab containing numbers incrementally

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a code that will duplicate and rename a template tab named "001". The thing is, I want each duplicated tab to be named as "001 +1". So the duplicated tabs' names would be "002,003,...,010,011...100,101, etc.

The number of duplicates will be decided by the number entered into a message box that will appear asking "How many copies would you like to make?". Also I would like for there to be no duplicates or tabs named "001 (2)" if more tab copies were to be added at a later time.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: If there's an existing tab "003" but no "002" should a new tab copied from "001" be named "004" or "002" ?

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the response. Ideally the next tab to be created would be the next lowest number. Therefore it would be "002" as in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
Sub Tester()
    CreateSheets 4
End Sub


'EDIT: added specific workbook reference to qualify sheet references
Sub CreateSheets(howMany As Long)
    Dim nm As String, sht As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, wb As Workbook

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    For n = 1 To howMany
        i = 2
        Do
            nm = Format(i, "000")
            Set sht = Nothing
            'see if this sheet exists...
            On Error Resume Next
            Set sht = wb.Sheets(nm)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If sht Is Nothing Then
                'get the sheet to copy the template after
                Set sht = wb.Sheets(Format(i - 1, "000"))
                wb.Sheets("001").Copy after:=sht
                wb.Sheets(sht.Index + 1).Name = nm
                Exit Do 'made our copy
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Loop
    Next n
End Sub
```

Comment: When I run "Tester", I get the following error: "Run-time error '1004': Cannon rename a sheet to the same name as another sheet, a referenced object library or a workbook referenced by Visual Basic". This error popped up after attempting to perform the first duplication and named the tab "001 (2)".

Comment: I made a slight edit to make the sheet references more explicit - try that out.  If it still errors then let me know exactly what the existing sheet names are before you ran it, and whether you have any hidden sheets in your workbook (and if yes what their names are)

Comment: First, Thank you for helping me out with this.      There were 4 existing sheets before i ran it named: "SBOM", "001", "Dropdown Lists", & "Instructions". All of the sheets were unhidden and there were no other hidden tabs. When I run the code, it puts out the same error. When I hit debug, it  highlights "wb.Sheets(sht.Index + 1).Name = nm"

Comment: What's the value of `nm` when it fails?

Comment: The code fails at the first iteration, so I would assume that nm = 2 (Format: "002")